# Does the following sum converge?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Does the sum
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}C_n^k(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{k}{\alpha n}\right)
$$
converge, where $C_n^k$ is the  binomial coefficient  and $0 <\alpha <1$?

---

The above question has been [solved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/366433) by Iosif Pinelis. A variation is
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}C_n^k(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{k}{\alpha n}\right)^n.
$$
How can we handle this sum?

Comment: Changing your question in response to an answer is not the preferred behaviour.  You can ask a new question, but probably better first to try for yourself to see if @IosifPinelis's [methods](https://mathoverflow.net/a/366433) apply.  (Also, the question should be self contained, and not depend on the title.  I have edited accordingly, and also fixed the misspelling of @‍IosifPinelis's name.)

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\an{\lfloor a n \rfloor}$
Let $a:=\alpha\in(0,1)$. By induction on $m=0,1,\dots$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom nk(-1)^k\Big(1-\frac k{a n}\Big) \\ 
=(-1)^{m+1} (a+m-a n)\frac{m+1}{an (n-1)}\,\binom n{m+1}.$$
So, letting $S_n$ denote the sum in question, we have
$$S_n\sim(-1)^{\lfloor a n \rfloor+1}(a-\{a n\}) \,M_n,$$
where $\{a n\}$ is the fractional part of $a n$ and
$$M_n:=\frac1n\,\binom n{\an+1}.$$
Let now $n\to\infty$. Depending on the arithmetical properties of $a$, the factor $(-1)^{\lfloor a n \rfloor+1}$ will alternate between $1$ and $-1$ and the factor $a-\{na\}$ will oscillate between $a-1<0$ and $a>0$, whereas  $M_n\to\infty$, since eventually, for all large enough $n$, we have $\binom n{\an+1}\ge\min[\binom n2,\binom n{n-2}]=n(n-1)/2$. So, the sum $S_n$ will not converge to any limit.

---

For an illustration, here are the connected graphs $\{(n,c_a^n n^{3/2}\,S_n)\colon n=1,\dots,100\}$ for $a=1/3$ (left) and $a=\sqrt2-1$ (right), where $c_a:=a^a (1 - a)^{1 - a}\in(0,1)$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A variation of this sum is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\alpha n \rfloor}C_n^k(-1)^k(1-\frac{k}{\alpha n})^n$. Does this sum converge?

Comment: @RyanChen : Your question has been fully answered. If you have further questions then, for more reasons than one, I suggest you post them separately.

Comment: Thank you. I will first verify whether your method can be used to solve the new question.